# Why hough Transformation detect Same line twice

Tags: java, image-processing, edge-detection, hough-transform

After using canny edge detector my image looks like

[image: Image After Canny edge detector]

Then I use Hough transform to extract line. Sometimes I able to find four line. But sometimes Same line detect as two line.

[image: With hough Transformation]

I want to find four corner of the rectangle, so using hough transformation I try to take four line then solve them. But extra line gives me pain. How I can solve this problem.

For hough transformation I'm using modified code of
http://vase.essex.ac.uk/software/HoughTransform/HoughTransform.java.html

Comment: Without an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a **M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample) there isn't much we can do to help you. You say you modified a sample... in what specific way? Also, are you sure there isn't a problem in that sample to begin with?

Comment: Your lines are not perfectly straight and you might have several local minima in the hough space. Try to perform a smoothing within the `getLines` function. That should do the trick.